# Signal handling in c++

Tags: c++, handler, signals

im new in c++,i want to know when we need to use signal handling in our program?and i saw in some codes that they fork after setting up signal,what fork means here?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly recommend the book [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 2nd Edition](http://www.powells.com/biblio?isbn=9780321525949) as your guide to systems programming.

`fork(2)` spawns a new process; it is almost entirely a clone of the current process. But the differences are vast: the return value from `fork(2)` is different in parent and child, the child has a new `pid`, new `ppid`, and all filedescriptors that had their `FD_CLOEXEC` flag set will be closed in the child (see `fcntl(2)` for details). There are other differences, but this is a good start.

When setting up signal handlers, the most important things to keep in mind: **Use `sigaction(2)`** to install signal handlers, not `signal(3)`. `signal(3)` is unreliable and allows for losing signals. **You can't do much**. The list of allowed functions that you may call in a signal handler is in the `signal(7)` manpage. Using functions outside this list is dangerous and can create some very difficult bugs. You can also set flags in your program that are checked by your main event loop, so you can cleanly exit or print status or reload config files at appropriate times.

Comment: so we use fork for avoiding crash or freeze,yes?and when we use signal handling?thanks

Comment: @arash, `fork(2)` is the only mechanism available to spawn child processes. As @Colin says, every shell will call `fork()` when starting new programs. (But not for the reason he says. :) Before threading was widely available on Unix platforms, `fork(2)` was the primary mechanism for parallelizing computing tasks to take advantage of multiple CPUs or allowing programmers to use simpler blocking IO interfaces. `fork()` remains the only interface for spawning a new child program, in the common `fork(2)+exec` idiom. (See `execle(3)` and `execve(2)` manpages for details.)

Comment: @arash, signal handling is used when you want to do something "nice" when the user hits `^C`, or wants to reload the configuration with `kill $(pidof ushare) SIGHUP` or similar commands, or use `SIGIO`-driven asynchronous IO operations (see `O_ASYNC` flag in `open(2)` for details), clean up after dead children (see `wait4(2)` and `wait(2)` manpages), or wants to coordinate tasks with other processes very simply.

Answer (score 1):

Fork is a built-in function in C that causes the program to create a child instance of itself, which begins execution at the point fork was called.  Shells fork before running a command, which is good because if the command causes a crash or freeze, the forked instance of the program can be killed while keeping the parent alive.

Comment: `fork()` is not a "built-in function in C". `fork()` is defined in the [posix specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) (and earlier, also unix-centric, specifications). `fork()` is not specified in the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/standards.html#9899) or any other C standard.

Comment: so we use fork for avoiding crash or freeze,yes?and when we use signal handling?thanks